# How to queue requests in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I manage a physical locker with Django (DRF). Users fill out a form, authenticate via link sent to their e-mail, authorize via a pin displayed on the locker.

My view should handle three cases:

- If user authenticates and authorizes successfully, pin displayed on
  the locker is replaced with a generic message and the locker opens.
  (Already implemented)
- If the user fails to authorize within 3 minutes, locker pin is replaced with a generic message.
- If a new authorization request is made by user Foo, while authorization for user Bar is still incomplete, stack the request in
  a queue and wait for case 1. or case 2. to complete.

**How can I:**

- Implement a request queue, such that the pin displayed on the locker does not get overridden/replaced when a new request comes in?
- How can I wait 3 minutes for authorization to be completed before processing the next request?

View as is, in case it is useful:

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfirmationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if pin == form.cleaned_data['pin']:
                open_bay(jwt_token=jwt[1], pin=pin)
                display_generic_message(jwt_token=jwt[1])
                lock_bay(jwt_token=jwt[1], pin=pin)
                return render(request, 'static/pages/request-success.html')
            else:
                pass
    else:
        form = ConfirmationForm()
    return render(request, 'static/pages/confirmation.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Django is quite bad at multiprocessing/multithreading, that's why solutions for queued task often involve a Redis instance and one or more workers that will process the queue. For instance (but there are probably others): https://github.com/rq/django-rq

Answer (score 0):

in your model which u save the authorization u need to add a field of date_created or date_requested and must be a datetime field . then on each request you can check if 3 minutes has passed from date_requested which you saved .
you also need an is_authorized field to check if your user is authorized or not.
we assume that you are getting the user from email you sent .

```
user = get_object_or_404(User,email=kwargs['email'])
if user.date_request + timedelta(minutes=3) > datetime.datetime.now():
   "do your authorzing stuff ..."
else:
     return HttpResponse("you need to wait 3 minutes to request again")
```

Comment: Yet if there are no more requests, the 3 minutes delay would not be respected and the message would not be displayed. EDIT: and the queue would not be maintained

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store when the last authorization started, clear that timestamp if the user puts in the pin.

```
# models.py
class LockerUserQueue(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
    locker = models.ForeignKey("yourapp.Locker")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(index=True, auto_now_add=True)


class Locker(models.Model):
    last_authorization = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_queue = models.ManyToManyField(through=LockerUserQueue)

    class BadPin(Exception):
        pass

    def enqueue_user(self, user):
        self.user_queue.add(user)

    def process_authorization(self, user):
        # do authorization for user

    def process_pin(self, user, pin):
        self.last_authorization = None
        if validate_pin(user, pin):
            # pin OK logic
        else:
            raise self.BadPin

# views.py
def authorize_user(request, locker_id):
    locker = get_object_or_404(pk=locker_id)
    locker.enqueue_user(request.user)
    locker.save()
    return render(request, "authorization_started.html")

def open_bay_with_pin(request, locker_id):
    locker = get_object_or_404(pk=locker_id)
    pin = get_pin_from_request(request)
    try:
        # No matter if the pin is correct, the locker.last_authorization is cleared
        locker.process_pin(user, pin)
    except locker.BadPin:
        return render(request, "bad_pin.html")
    finally:
        locker.save()
    return render(request, "good_pin.html")



# management/commands/process_queue.py
# you would run this by
# $ python manage.py process_queue
class Command(BaseCommand):

    @transaction.atomic
    def process_queue(self):
        # you probably want to put the 3 min delay in your settings.py
        # so you don't end up with a magic value here
        for locker in LockerUserQueue.objects.filter(
            Q(locker__last_authorization__isnull=True)|Q(locker__last_authorization__gt=now() - timedelta(minutes=3))
        ).order_by("created_at").values_list("locker", flat=True).distinct():
            locker.process_authorization()

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            self.process_queue()
            # you don't want to keep querying the DB when there's nothing in the queue
            sleep(5)
```

The code above shows how you would do it using the database as the queue, in a low volume use case this should be just fine. If the volume is high, I would store the locker `last_authorization` in faster storage, like `redis`, the queue can be maintained in `redis` as well. But the logic behind would be the same.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/